# Pandas nested groupby and sum unique values based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({"ID1": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"],
                     "ID2": ["k", "k", "k", "k","k", "k", "j", "j", "j"],
                     "val": [18, 19, 20, 18, 19, 20, 34, 35, 37]
                     })

data
```

*Output:*

```
    ID1 ID2 val
0   a   k   18
1   a   k   19
2   a   k   20
3   b   k   18
4   b   k   19
5   b   k   20
6   c   j   34
7   c   j   35
8   c   j   37
```

I'm trying to get the average of `val` by grouping by `ID1` and finally need the `sum` grouping by `ID2`

```
(data
 .assign(val_id1_avg = data.groupby("ID1")["val"].transform("mean"))
 .groupby("ID2")
 .agg(val_avg = ("val_id1_avg", lambda x: np.sum(x.unique())),
      volume=("ID1", 'nunique'))
 .reset_index())
```

*Output:*

```
   ID2  val_avg volume
0   j   35.333333   1
1   k   19.000000   2
```

How can I drop duplicates based on `ID1` and sum the `val_id1_avg`??

**Desired Output:**

```
ID2 val_avg    Volume
0   k   38.00   1
1   j   35.33   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is trick, replace duplicates by `ID1` to `val_id1_avg` by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df = (data.assign(val_id1_avg = data.groupby("ID1")["val"].transform("mean").mask(data['ID1'].duplicated()))
          .groupby("ID2", as_index=False, sort=False)
          .agg(val_avg = ("val_id1_avg",'sum'),
               volume=("ID1", 'nunique'))
         )

print (df)
  ID2    val_avg  volume
0   k  38.000000       2
1   j  35.333333       1
```

**Details**:

```
print (data.assign(val_id1_avg = data.groupby("ID1")["val"].transform("mean").mask(data['ID1'].duplicated()))
          )

  ID1 ID2  val  val_id1_avg
0   a   k   18    19.000000
1   a   k   19          NaN
2   a   k   20          NaN
3   b   k   18    19.000000
4   b   k   19          NaN
5   b   k   20          NaN
6   c   j   34    35.333333
7   c   j   35          NaN
8   c   j   37          NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm doing some other agg with duplicate values, can it be done without dropping duplicates`.drop_duplicates(['ID1','ID2','val_id1_avg']`??

Comment: @Ailurophile - Now answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can try grouping by both ids to calculate mean and then group by second one and use sum:

```py
(data.groupby(["ID1", 'ID2'])["val"].mean()).groupby(['ID2']).sum()
```

Output:

```
ID2
j    35.333333
k    38.000000
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can it be possible to do it inside first level groupby `groupby("ID2")`. The reason is I'm using other aggregations.

Comment: @Ailurophile can you please give a more extended example?